# ucheed.com’s server DNS address could not be found. hosted domain route 53 on some networks

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, plesk, amazon-route53

I have a problem with a domain name that is registered with GoDaddy and DNS hosted with Amazon Route 53 and hosted by Plesk on EC2 server on AWS. 
on some internet connections I get the following message:
This site can’t be reached

ucheed.com’s server DNS address could not be found.
Search Google for ucheed
ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Comment: DNS servers usually use some sort of caching. It may take some time for the new records to propagate.

Comment: Please provide the domain name.

Comment: ucheed.org is the domain name